# Nested propagation in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, nested, propagation

I'm trying to learn how to use Hibernate and Spring and came into some problem. Wanted to check on my own skin how Propagation.NESTED works. And there is my code:

```
@Component
@Transactional
public class CompanyServiceImpl implements CompanyService {
    @Autowired
    private CompanyDao dao;
...
    @Override
    public void testNested(int id,String name) {
        User user=dao.getUser(id);
        user.setName(name);
        notValidNested(id,name+"new");
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation=Propagation.NESTED)
    public void notValidNested(int id,String name) {
        dao.getUser(id).setName(name);
        TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
    }
}

@Component
public class CompanyDaoImpl implements CompanyDao {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
...
    @Override
    public User getUser(int id) {

        return em.find(User.class, id);
    }
}
```

And Spring's configuration

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages= {"util.spring.test","service","dao"})
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class SpringConfiguration {
    @Bean
      public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        System.out.println("entityManagerFactory - initialization started");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("ORM");
        entityManagerFactoryBean.getJpaPropertyMap().put(BeanValidationIntegrator.MODE_PROPERTY, ValidationMode.NONE);

       return entityManagerFactoryBean;
      }

     @Bean
      public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        System.out.println("transactionManager - initialization started");
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        transactionManager.setRollbackOnCommitFailure(true);
        return transactionManager;
      }
}
```

I have read little bit about `NESTED` and thought that this code would (let's assume that i made `companyService.testNested(7,"newName")`  change name of User with id 7 to "newName". Sadly name doesn't change at all. If I replace `TransactionAspectSupport.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();` with `throw new RuntimeException();` and add to annotation `rollbackFor=RuntimeException.class` the result is the same. I have read a little bit about propagation, but sadly I have no idea whats wrong with my code. 
One possibility that comes to my mind is that my driver doesn't support savepoints (that are used in `NESTED`) but the same thing happens when I change `NESTED` to `REQUIRES_NEW`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are calling a method inside the same class.  Spring does not have an opportunity to intercept the call and apply the `@Transactional` attributes.  If you move it to a separate class, you should see the behavior you are looking for.

Comment: That was the case. Now I only get "JpaDialect does not support savepoints - check your JPA provider's capabilities", but at list it works :) .

Comment: Any idea to make it work? (Requires_NEW works just fine).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using "NESTED" exactly?  Would "REQUIRED" accomplish what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is not with Transaction, it may be the case of detached entity. Try calling entityManager.save()  or entityManager.merge() method after changing the value.